# SDK r21 - ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, eclipse

Since upgrading to SDK r21, this is an error that pops up frequently. The only way I've been able to fix it is to clear my workspace and re-import the project.
I've tried everything mentioned in other questions, renaming 'lib' to libs', fix project properties, etc. The class in question in my main activity, and does not reside in a .jar.  It seems like the class loader path is incorrect, but I'm not sure how to fix this issue. My source has not changed since I upgraded from SDK r16, which had no such issues.

```
04-30 11:34:44.084: W/dalvikvm(3802): Link of class 'Lcom/absds/proj/App;' failed
04-30 11:34:44.084: W/dalvikvm(3802): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x413ea540)
04-30 11:34:44.094: E/AndroidRuntime(3802): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-30 11:34:44.094: E/AndroidRuntime(3802): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.absds.proj/com.absds.proj.App}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.absds.proj.App
```

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.absds.proj"
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
android:versionName="13.5.0" android:versionCode="135" >

<application
    android:theme="@style/Theme"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/appName"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:persistent="true">

    <activity
        android:name=".App"..
```

Comment: I have no idea what you think "SDK r17" is. The Android developer tools and ADT plugin for Eclipse are up to R21.

Comment: Thanks, I typed in the API version instead. Fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying every suggestion found in https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/-bholnLurs8 and on every other thread on SO regarding this, deleting the project and readding it to my workspace seemed to be the only solution.